# How to get the numeric id of an graph in igraph?

Tags: igraph

I have a small network "g" and I want to know the numeric ID associated to each edge of this graph, how can I do it?

```
g<-graph_from_literal(A---B,B----C,E--F,G---H,D--H)
```

It suppose that each edge have a numeric ID, in this case, A=1,B=2,C=3,E=4,F=5,G=6,H=7,D=8

And it is easy to know cause is a small network, but, in the case with a large network, how do know the numeric id of each edge or a pair of nodes in specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the vertex ID from its name:

```
> which(V(g)$name == "C")
[1] 3
```

Getting the edge ID from the endpoints of an edge:

```
> get.edge.ids(g, c("B", "C"))
[1] 2
```